# Deploy Blazor WebAssembly App ASP.NET Core hosted to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, blazor

I have a **3-projects solution structure (Client,Server,Shared)** in Visual Studio 2019. What I exactly did to create it can be described as:

- [GUI] *BlazorApp -> Blazor WebAssembly App -> checbox ticked [v] ASP.NET Core hosted*

which is equal to:

- [CMD] *dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted*

I would like to **deploy this projects to Azure**, but I am facing some problems:

1. When I tried to use continous GitHub deploy and attached my branch to it, I got error which basically said that 3.1 version is not supported (highest was 3.0). It's weird, while setting up WebApp server on Azure I chose .NET Core 3.1 (LTS) option [hosted on Linux, no other option]
2. If I would like to publish it manually from VS2019, which "project" should I deploy?

---

I assume that this 3-project template is just a friendly hand from Microsoft so I don't have to create 2 separate project and what I am trying to do could be done just by deploying two **separate** WebApps:

1. REST API built with .NET Core 3.1 ( mix .Shared and .Server projects
   **OR** just create WebAPI project)
2. Blazor WebAssembly App (so called client-side)

Although, if this can be done all at once - I would prefer it.

---

Thank You in advance!

---

***EDIT 1 (10.03.20 10:15)***

This is my *.yml file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish artifacts'
```

Configuration of WebApp:

- Publish: Code
- Runtime stack: .NET Core 3.1 (LTS)
- OS: Linux

***EDIT 2 (10.03.20 10:31)***

Got the following error:

*Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip. Please restrain the search pattern.*

***EDIT 3 (10.03.20 10:15)***

Build finally succeded, after I changed the specific zip file from this list (all the items in this folder are visible on a screenshot. I chose WebApp.zip)
***But - I go to the url and I am only seeing "Your app service is up and running" default screen..***

[image: Build folder]

Comment: Please see: [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I've been on this page already, could not find a solution that would solve my specific problem here :/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue, instead of going through Github directly, I used Azure DevOps to pull from Github, build and then deploy to my webapp.

You'll find a great tutorial here.

https://youtu.be/jRgLSMlp28U

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will try it, hope it won't be messy with all the resources groups, plans, web apps and dbs. Is iit possible to use DevOps using a free 12-month plan (student)?

Comment: Absolutely, it shouldn't be an issue. I'm fairly new to this as well, but with DevOps you should be able to do just about everything you need.

Comment: I tried to do it as it was shown on the video, but had a problem with targetting a *.zip file. It tells that there more than one and it does not know which one to targer...

Comment: I'll try to look deeper into it today to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Can you share your YAML file?

Answer (score 0):

Azure build agents don't have the latest .NET SDK installed.
Add this to your yaml file:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use latest preview of .Net Core sdk 3.x'
  inputs:
    version: 3.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

Comment: Also, I had a problem deploying preview DLLs to Linux WebApp. I created a windows WebApp and the deployment succeeded. Ping me if you need more details